# extract upper case from the title pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a dataset, in which the column looks like this:

```
col
AMPCO Impact Socket
MEGGAR HARLEY Impact Socket
```

Is there any way where I can be able to extract `AMPCO, MEGGAR HARLEY`?
Even if I can get MEGGAR from second sentence, that would also work.

I tried `res = list(filter(lambda c: c.isupper(), test_str[:1]))` and many other ways but I am not getting what I want

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b').str.join(' ')
print (df)
                               col            new
0              AMPCO Impact Socket          AMPCO
1      MEGGAR HARLEY Impact Socket  MEGGAR HARLEY
```